# How to get text of role=alert with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I want get text of role=alert from HTML page, I can find the element but I'm not able to get the text.

`<div class="alert alert-danger no-margin" role="alert">
        customer.dashboard.InvalidCode`

To find the element I used:

`driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'alert')]"));`

but if I try to get "customer.dashboard.InvalidCode" every time I get empty string.

Comment: Your XPath selector is very broad. You might be selection other elements that contains the alert class name. Are you sure this is the only element? Can you post the code you use to get the text.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I solved using  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'alert alert-danger no-margin')]")); to find the element and after  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'alert alert-danger no-margin')]")).Text; to get the text, now it is working!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until element is visible to get text:

```
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))

IWebElement alert = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("div.alert.alert-danger")));
string alertText = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(alert)).Text;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this xpath:`//div[contains(@class, 'alert alert-danger no-margin')]` instead of `//div[contains(@class, 'alert')]`

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'alert alert-danger no-margin')]")).Text;
```